# Open camera in android webview

Tags: android-studio, webview, camera

Please dont mark it as duplicate.

I am trying to open camera in android webview. But none of the solution available on stackoverflow is working. No code is working .
i have tried all and all solutions available on this site. 
one of the solution is saying to use os-fileup library. But i am new to android and i dont know how to use that. 
So please help me with it.

Camera is opening fine in android browser like chrome etc. but not working in app. I have tried all permissions

This is the code i am using in HTML.

Comment: Post your attempts, solutions and variations that you've tried and the questions you've read and found not the be helpful in your case. That will increase your chance of getting an answer.

Comment: if you search this stackoverflow with this query
open camera in android webview
you will see a couple of result on first page
i have tried all of them